# PHP code within Javascript - how to transfer variable

Tags: mysql, variables

in my webpage, I have the following code:

```
<?php
echo "<td class=\"action\">
<a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"deleteline(" . $row['id'] . ")\"> </a>
?>

<script>
function deleteline(a) {
    var r=window.confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer le viager " + a +"?");
    if (r)
    {
    <?php
    $test="<script> document.write(a);</script>";
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db("xxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    $strSQL =("update viagers set statut='deleted' where id=????");
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    mysql_close();
        ?>;
    }
        }
</script>
```

In a php table, i have an small delete icon in each row. I want the user to be able to click on it so it deletes the record in the sql db. I can't find a way to retrieve the 'a' variable in the php code of my script function (replace by ????).

Could you please help?

thanks and regards
Harold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix javascript and PHP like that. Make another PHP file for deletion, and send the `a` by javascript to the file through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code inside javascript is not a good approach. As lqbal Fauzi mentioned, send a variable - row id by javascript to the php file through AJAX - or as I do below, by using JQUERY. In php file, you can do your database stuff and if wanted, send some result back to your application.

In your HTML file you have to have scripts with JQUERY library source files.. Download these 2 files from here:

https://mega.co.nz/#!IUAFCYZb!Cu0mQoAVAkJHzqvac40-RYA-n3TnhYGtoazw5k_PMv4
https://mega.co.nz/#!hABhFDiS!Q_L8rERVq8330zrOxXXen0uxmLCes7zYG6J6SCncz6M

and save/copy those files into the folder containing your html file.

Your html file should look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Your page Title</title>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function yourJavascriptfunction(sender){

 var r=window.confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer le viager " + sender.name +"?");
if (r)
  {
   $.post("YourPHPPageToAccessDatabaseAndSendResult.php", {
    UserID:sender.name
     })
    .success(function(data){    
     //some code on data return if you want
      alert(data); //should pop up with message saying "Hello, this is the result data"
    })
    .fail(function(error){
      alert("Unable to retrieve data from the server");
    }); 
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" name="YourRowID" onclick="yourJavascriptfunction(this)" > your button text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the php file named YourPHPPageToAccessDatabaseAndSendResult.php which has to be in this case in the same directory as your html file  following code:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","USER","YOURPASSWORD") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("DatabaseName",$connection);
    $UserID= $_POST['UserID'];

    $strSQL =("update viagers set statut='deleted' where id=$UserID");
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    mysql_close();

    //by printing with echo you sent some data that you want return to your html file
   echo "Hello, this is the result data";
?>
```

**The above code is not tested for functionality, there might be some typos, but the logic in there should work and help you in the future**

---

### Don't forget to substitute the YourRowID in button name in html file to whatever you need, and set correct USER, YOURPASSWORD and DatabaseName in the php file.

---

Comment: Thanks very much! it works pretty well except the echo json_encode("Hello, this is the result data"); which does not return any value to the main page. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: I am glad it works.. yes, I tested it now, why it doesn't return anything..change the success function to following:
.success(function(data){    
      alert(data);
    })

and also change change the echo command in php file to:  echo "Hello, this is the result data";

Comment: May I ask why you unaccepted my answer, is there something wrong?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I actually followed the above advice and created a php with PDO to process the sql query. it seems to be closed to the market practice! thanks again!